# How to show morning and night for time

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to say I eat dinner at 8 at night? I want to show that 8 in in night not in the morning or some thing else.

For example:

> I go to school at 8 in the morning.
>
> I eat dinner at 6 at night.

Comment: We use the abbreviatioms _a.m._ and _p.m._ to denote the time before and after 12:00 noon respectively. _8:00 a.m._ denotes 8 in the morning, for example.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - True, but conversationally, there's nothing wrong with using "in the morning" or "at night."

Comment: I hope my comment isn't taken to mean "We use _only_ the abbreviations..."!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phrases like:

- *in the morning*
- *in the afternoon*
- *in the evening*
- *at night*

are common ways to ensure a given time of day is not ambiguous, particularly in conversation.

Regarding one of your particular examples, I think:

> I eat dinner at six at night.

seems a little redundant, since most people eat dinner around that time. You could just say, "I eat dinner at six." But for other statements, that would be fine, like:

> I walk my dog at six at night.

As one user mentioned in a comment, we can also use AM or PM, particularly in more formal contexts. For example, I probably wouldn't send an email to everyone in my office saying:

> We plan to run the updates at seven at night.

Instead, I'd write:

> We plan to run the updates at 7 PM.

Comment: Chicago Manual of Style, AP Stylebook, MLA Style Manual, and Merriam-Webster dictionary all tell us that the preferred style is to use lower case letters with periods after them in "a.m." and "p.m." But who elected them, anyway?

Comment: @P.E.Dant - I would follow their preferred style if I was submitting a paper to a journal. I don't usually consult them when I'm composing an email for co-workers.

Comment: Heh! Of course not, neither would I, but maybe that belongs in the answer somewhere. (The style guides also speak of small caps w/o full stops, but without real typographical tools that's hard to manage.)